# Apache HttpClient return cached body on conditional request

Tags: caching, apache-httpclient-4.x, cache-control, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using CachingHttpClient implementation of HttpClient from Apache. And having the following scenario:

I made a request for a resource that returned a response with a header:
    **Cache-Control:max-age=5**.
So CachingHttpClient caches the response.

I following I'm making a conditional request for the same resource using **If-Modified-Since**. And I get a response with status code 304 No modified (btw it does not even checks the server). Without a response body. Which is fine, but I would like to access the cached body, since if its not updated I want to use that.

The question is:

**Is there a convenient way to access the cached response from the first call?**

(Using org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-cache; version 4.5.2)

server side:

```
    @RequestMapping("/number")
        public int getNumber(HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {
            log.info("Number gen called");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + 5);
            return random.nextInt();
        }
```

client side:

```
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/number");

httpget.setHeader("If-Modified-Since", java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.
        format(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT")).minusSeconds(1)));

HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpget);
        log.info("code: " + resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        // here fails because no body on 2. call
String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(resp);
```

Http Client Init

```
    @Bean
    public HttpClient httpClient() {
        return CachingHttpClients.createMemoryBound();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if I configure the cache explicitly, I can use that cache object directly too, so this was a typical RTFM problem, my bad.

```
@Bean
public HttpCacheStorage httpCacheStorage() {
    CacheConfig cacheConfig = CacheConfig.custom()
            .setMaxCacheEntries(1000)
            .setMaxObjectSize(8192)
            .build();
    HttpCacheStorage cacheStorage = new BasicHttpCacheStorage(cacheConfig);
    return cacheStorage;
}
```